# Cannot find reference 'dt' in 'time.pyi | time.pyi'

Tags: python, game-engine

I tried to make a little game with the Ursina Engine, but i when i tried to run it, I got this message: **Cannot find reference 'dt' in 'time.pyi | time.pyi'.** I don't know why it doesn't work can someone help me? here is the code:

```
def update():
    if held_keys['a']:
        test_square.x -= 4 * time.dt


app = Ursina()

test_square = Entity(model='quad', color=color.red, scale=(1, 4), position=(5, 4))
app.run()
```

Comment: sounds like the `time.dt` you have on the third line doesn't refer to anything. Maybe a typo? Where's that `time` coming from? Are you sure you're calling the right stuff?

Comment: I thought that's a function from Ursina but maybe it thinks that time.dt comes from the library time...

Answer (score 2):

I looked into the files of the Ursina Game engine and `time.dt` or `Time.DeltaTime` is defined in `ursina/main.py` as:

```
def _update(self, task):
    # time between frames
    time.dt = globalClock.getDt() * application.time_scale`
```

If you add `dt = globalClock.getDt() * application.time_scale` to your file it should work

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to get the time since the last before window has been created with Ursina(). So it doesn't exist yet.

Just move app = Ursina() above your update loop.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure `update()` is declared after `app = Ursina()` and before `app.run()`

And that you imported ursina correctly.

```py
from ursina import *
#or
from ursina import time
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that

from ursina import time

is declared

Answer (score 0):

Ensure that you have imported the correct module classes. You could either do...

> `from ursina import time`

or...

> `from ursina import *`

Using the second one allows you to have a comprehensive cover of all you would ever need to import except the `ursina.prefabs` module classes such as `ursina.prefabs.first_person_controller`.

If you use the first, then a variable called `dt` would be the `time.dt`. This is why it is better to use `from ursina import *`

Thank you for your time, I hope this helps.